# Take the Layout from a Blender file and use it for default start file

Tags: workspaces

I created a Layout for a Blender file. I want to take this Layout and import it into a blank scene to save the startup file with it. I have not found a satisfying answer how to do it. When I see Blender File elements, in the Layouts can be seen. Is there no way to export it then import it for the blank file?

Answer (score 0):

Use *Copy* from the Blender File - Workspaces in the file that is using that layout and then on a separately open Blender instance that is new scene *Paste*.

It will add the layout on top as a new tab, then clicking it will make the blank scene same layout as the file that already uses it. Then of course

Then go to *File - Defaults - Save Startup File*.

Comment: Workspaces are regular datablocks, they can be appended or linked from other files like any other information in Blender.